# How do I create a matplotlib animation with multiple animated functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create an animation of growing concentric circles in python. As the program runs, more circles should generate from the centre and grow outwards

Right now I have this, which just creates one expanding circle.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 128), ylim=(0, 128))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    r = np.sqrt(i)
    x = r * np.cos(theta) + 64
    y = r * np.sin(theta) + 64
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1000, interval=10, blit=True)


plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

How do I modify my code so that new growing circles generate from the middle to create growing concentric circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a list of lines, and add a new one every few frames with a smaller radius

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 128), ylim=(0, 128))
# Keep a list of lines instead of a single one
lines = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


def init():
    for line in lines:
        line.set_data([], [])
    return lines


def animate(i):
    # Add a new line every 100 frames
    if i // 100 >= len(lines):
        new_line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
        lines.append(new_line)
    for line_num, line in enumerate(lines):
        theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        # Reduce the radius of the new lines
        r = np.sqrt(i - 100 * line_num)
        x = r * np.cos(theta) + 64
        y = r * np.sin(theta) + 64
        line.set_data(x, y)
    return lines


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1000, interval=10, blit=True)


plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```